# Input In Other Language Other than English

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I am making a application in php, in which i want some other language as input.

Mean if someone types "A"from US English Keyboard it should be "ए" in hindi.

How can it be done?

Dont want to use graphical keyboard.

Wants to make something like http://hindi.changathi.com/

Comment: The example you point to doesn't translate letter by letter, it translates words. How would you translate English letters when there aren't an exact counterpart in other alphabets?

Comment: Ok.........Tell me for both please

Comment: ...both what? Translating words can be done, it's not easy and you need a massive db with all the words in each language, unless you use a service. This question is way to broad for SO, though. It can be done in many ways. You should do some research and try something. If you get stuck in something _specific_, comeback and we can take it from there.

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue which can be answered in a few paragraphs. I would suggest you find a development forum (perhaps [Quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when/if you have specific coding issues, come back to Stack Overflow and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: Ok.... tell me about letters by letters

Comment: Did you give up?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the logic is behind the calculator, and I'm not sure if you really want PHP, but it just substitutes a Hindi character for an English Latin character.  So in either PHP or JavaScript just replace:

PHP

```
$eng = array('A', 'B','C'); //etc...
$hin = array('अ','ब','क'); //etc...

$result = str_replace($eng, $hin, $mystring);
```